# Kendo Grid - Reordering columns with two columns containing the same data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

A little background on how my grid works:

My grid is making use of `.Sortable()`, `.Reorderable()`,  `.Filterable()` and  `.ColumnMenu()`. On the `dataBound` event, the grid saves the state of the grid (column order, items per page, current pagination page, and column sorting [asc and desc]). This is so when a user comes back to that page, their settings are reloaded in the grid when some initializing Javascript makes a query on the grid.

My issue comes into play when I have the same data for two columns:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridDataType>()
    .Name("ActiveThreats_Grid")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Bound(r => r.Id).Title("<input id='checkAll', type='checkbox', class='check-box' />")
          .Sortable(false)
          .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='check_row' id='#= Id#' />")
          .Filterable(false);

      columns.Bound(r => r.OtherField).Title("Other Field");

      columns.Bound(r => r.Id).Title("ID").Hidden(true);
    })
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Filterable()
    .ColumnMenu()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        // Other HtmlHelpers here
    )
```

What I've noticed, is if I have the same `data-field` attribute and I am using the `.Reorderable()` HtmlHelper, the grid reorders the first `r.Id` column to the same position where the second `r.Id` column appears.

### Q: Is there an HtmlHelper or way to change the `data-field` attribute output to prevent `.Reorderable()` from ordering the two identical columns next to each other?

Comment: Hi @Fillip, apologies for my misunderstanding of the question and I have taken down my solution as it wasn't linked to the question.

Comment: Can you please verify if this is what you are looking for: http://dojo.telerik.com/IteH

Comment: Close... That is the functionality I'm using (though, I'm init'ing it via the Kendo ASP.NET wrapper rather than JS), but I was looking to some how change/specify the data-field attribute for a given column. Preferably in the Kendo ASP.NET wrapper.